# Beans fail to initailize when rabbit is initially down

Tags: java, amqp, spring-amqp

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader | localhost-startStop-1 |     Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleListenerContainer' defined
 in class path resource [com/company/product/api/config/amqp/InternalAmqpConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation v
ia factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
```

If Rabbit is down before my Spring MVC application is up a number of the beans that depend on the `CachingConnectionFactory` fail to initialize. Like the following:

```
 @Autowired
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleistenerContainer(
    @Qualifier("internal") CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    RabbitAdmin admin) {

    for(Listeners listener : Listeners.values()) {
        Queue q = new Queue(listener.queue, true, true, true);
        admin.declareQueue(q);
        admin.declareBinding(
            BindingBuilder.bind(q)
                .to(new TopicExchange(listener.exchange, true, false))
                .with((listener.appendWildcard) ? listener.routingKey + ""
                    + ".*" : listener.routingKey)
        );
    }

    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainerFactory = new
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

    listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    return listenerContainerFactory;
}
```

This fails and does not recover since the bean wasn't initialized because one of this dependencies are missing. I thought about using the setting a `ConnectionListener` on the `CachingConnectionFactory` but then those objects wouldn't be accessible as beans. Any suggestions would be helpful. I'm sure there may be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your bindings etc as `@Bean`s instead of declaring them yourself.

Add a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` and it will automatically perform the declarations when the connection is established.

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment...

However, you are performing your own declarations:

```
admin.declareQueue(q);
admin.declareBinding(...
```

These will fail if the broker is not available unless you add try/catch. You can also set `ignoreDeclarationExceptions` on the admin, but you really don't need to do these declarations yourself. The admin will declare them automatically as soon as a container establishes a connection.

**EDIT2**:

> Why would they get declared? ...

Because that's the way it's designed; please read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#broker-configuration) scroll down for the java configuration of `Binding` etc.

The `RabbitAdmin` (if declared in the context) registers itself as a connection listener. When a connection is established, the admin looks for all `Queue`, `Exchange` and `Binding` `@Bean`s in the context and declares them when the connection is established.

You are subverting this "lazy" declaration by binding directly from the bean definition, which requires the broker to be available and the context will fail to initialize if there's no connection.

Simply declare your required `Binding`s in the context, and the admin will take care of it for you when the broker is available. The listener container will keep trying to connect, according to its `recoveryInterval` and the declarations will occur when it is eventually successful.

Comment: Why would they get declared? I have like four different routing keys I need to bind to. The `@RabbitListener` only allows for named queues but not routing keys...unless that has changed. I left out that part of the source code since it has references to the product. I don't want to subscribe to the wildcard for the queue, only a few specific routing keys.

Comment: Can I return a `List<Binding>` will that also be declared? I have an enum that use to build my bindings. I would prefer to have the logic separated.

Comment: No; there is currently no support for a bean that is a `List<Binding>`; feel free to open a JIRA 'improvement' issue.